# How to fix error handling timer () run many times in kotlin?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, timer, kotlin-android-extensions

```
class HomeActivity : BaseActivity(), View.OnClickListener,
    NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
   private var mTimer:Timer? = null
   private var mTimerTask: TimerTask? = null

   override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        // todo ..
        syncLocationToServer()
        // todo...
   }

   private fun syncLocationToServer() {       
        mTimer = Timer()
        mTimerTask = object : TimerTask(){
                override fun run() {     
                   Log.d("test", getDateTimeLocal())
                }
        }
      mTimer?.schedule(mTimerTask, 0, 60000L)
    }
}
```

I want to ask.
In the code above, I want to execute Log.d ("test", getDateTimeLocal ()) every 1 minute.

But sometimes when 1 minute occurs, Log.d ("test", getDateTimeLocal ()) is called many times. I don't understand why, please help me??

Answer (score 0):

**Try this Timer Function:**

```
private fun syncLocationToServer() {       
    Timer().schedule(object : TimerTask() {
        override fun run() {
            TODO("Do something")
        }
    }, 2000)
}
```

Comment: Can you explain why my code causes the error to run multiple times in 1s?

Comment: Can't Really Say what's the problem but I guess its the scheduler.

Comment: BTW Check This web reference and grab the first function, its super easy for scheduler work!

https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.concurrent/java.util.-timer/schedule.html